# Count the string value, based on count print the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list:

`a = ['the','is','the','for','who','the','which']`.

I want to count the occurrence of 'the'. For example, here 'the' appears 3 times, so it will print: `the1,the2,the3`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `count` method:

```py
['the','is','the','for','who','the','which'].count('the')
```

In your case, you could do something like:

```py
count = a.count('the')
print(",".join(f'the{idx + 1}' for idx in range(count)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = ['the','is','the','for','who','the','which']
result = [item + str(idx) for idx, item in enumerate(filter(lambda _: _ == "the", a), 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use The `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['the','is','the','for','who','the','which']
dict_a = Counter(a)
n = dict_a["the"]    # number of occurrence of word "the" in list a 

for i in range(1,n+1):
    print("the%d" % i)
```

The `dict_a = Counter(a)` gives a dictionary that has unique words as keys of the dictionary and the number of occurrences of each word in the list as the value of each key.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['the','is','the','for','who','the','which']
j=1
for val in a:
    if val == 'the':
        print(val + str(j))
        j+=1
```

Comment: In my head, `j` should start at 0 and `j += 1` should happen before the print. It's nitpicking but it makes more sense to me to start the counter at zero.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use regex for this, as this gives you more freedom when comparig strings. Since you also want to append the number of occurrences to a string, you might need a loop.

Here is my take on your question:

```py
import re

a = ['the','is','the','for','who','the','which']

out = []

value = "the"
occur = 0

for input in a:
    result = re.search(value, input)
    if result:
        occur += 1
        out.append(value + str(occur))

for output in out:
    print(output)
```

Changing the `value` variable will make your code try to match other strings (say `"who"`). You could also use the [regex101](https://regex101.com/) website to find best regex fits for all cases.

Below is the resulting outout:

```sh
the1
the2
the3
```